# Convert given UTC timestamp string to unix timestamp

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I'm struggling with this small snippet:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

start = "2022-05-14T10:00:00"
start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(start)
start_unix = time.mktime(start_date.timetuple())

print(start_unix)
#1652515200.0
```

The start date regardless how it looks is in UTC while I'm in a different timezone. Python threats this datetime string/object as it would be in the same timezone I am.
How to convert the datetime string object the easiest way to get a proper UNIX timestamp?
The expected result should be:

```
1652522400.0
```

Comment: @FObersteiner this is exactly what I needed, please post it as a reply for me to upvote it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the tzinfo of the resulting datetime object to UTC (`replace` method), then call `.timestamp()` method of the aware datetime object. Ex:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

start = "2022-05-14T10:00:00"
start_unix = datetime.fromisoformat(start).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()

print(start_unix)
# 1652522400.0
```